# Vim complete option not worknig

Tags: c++, vim, autocomplete

I have `complete=.,w,b,u,t,i`. Using `:h cpt` you can find this:

> `i` scan current and included files

I have the below c++ code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector <int> v;

    v.push_
}
```

When I press C-n in front of `v.push_` vim says `-- Keyword completion (^N^P) Pattern not found`.

How can I fix it?

I'm using vim 8.1 on ubuntu 20.04.

UPD:

```
:checkpath! output
--- Included files in path ---
<vector>  NOT FOUND
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: 1. Edit that sample file. 2. Do `:checkpath!`. 3. Add the output to your question. Your `:help 'path'` may not be properly set.

Comment: @romainl I added the output

Comment: Incorrect `path` hypothesis confirmed. The current answer should help you get what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @romainl pointed out, your path doesn't include your `c++` directory in `/usr/include/c++/`, so you only need to add this directory to your path in your user runtime directory `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/cpp.vim`. For example, this should be enough for your purposes as it will read files recursively based on the initial matches from your include command.

```
setlocal path=.,,/usr/include/c++/11/
```

You can also play with wildcards as described in `:h file-searching`.

Comment: I added this but problem is still there and !checkpath! output is the same as before

Comment: Please confirm you have the same directory in `/usr/include/c++/11/`, since it is possible you have other version. Also check if this change is actually being used by running `:set path?` and finally, make sure you're performing your tests in buffers with filetype `cpp` (`set filetype?`)

Comment: I found out that I have version 9. Problem solved by changing 11 to 9. Thank you